# Calculate the quality of the GPS signal iPhone

Tags: iphone, swift, gps

I am developing an application very similar to Runtastic. 
I have a problem to understand what is the quality of the GPS signal.
If I understand it you need to use the property horizontalAccuracy but I don't understand what are the range for the quality of the signal can be considered as excellent, good, or no signal.
Can you help me ? 
I have found several examples on the internet but then when I go to apply the values I don't get what I want.
This is my code:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            //assign new image
            if(newLocation.horizontalAccuracy < 0){
                //No Signal
                self.qualitaSegnale.text = "\(newLocation.horizontalAccuracy)";
                self.imageGPS.image = UIImage(named: "gps_signal_ko");
            }
            else if(newLocation.horizontalAccuracy > 163){
                self.qualitaSegnale.text = "\(newLocation.horizontalAccuracy)";
                self.imageGPS.image = UIImage(named: "gps_signal_peer");
            }
            else if (newLocation.horizontalAccuracy > 48){
                self.qualitaSegnale.text = "\(newLocation.horizontalAccuracy)";
                self.imageGPS.image = UIImage(named: "gps_signal_peer");
            }
            else {
                self.qualitaSegnale.text = "\(newLocation.horizontalAccuracy)";
                self.imageGPS.image = UIImage(named: "gps_signal_ok");
            }
        }
```

Thanks to all for your availability.

Vincenzo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So anything below 48 is considered good. I'd say anything below 10 is excellent.

Source: I've been messing with similar stuff recently, and it appears the best reading I can get is a radius of 5 metres. I would consider 5 metres to be the best possible reading at this point in time.

In addition to:

```
if(newLocation.horizontalAccuracy < 0){
```

I'd also check:

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
```

Because there are probably going to be errors if horizontalAccuracy is less than 0.